# Opening a net.tcp connection from a WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7, net.tcp

My situation looks like this:

I have a WCF service acting as a proxy between clients and an internal WCF service that is actually handling the requests. This service is hosted in IIS 7.

I have added a service reference to my project and included the binding and endpoint configuration data into my web.config. The internal service offers two bindings: basicHttpBinding and netTcpBinding. 
If I use basicHttpBinding, everything works as expected. However, using netTcpBinding results in the dreaded error message:

*"The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:09:59.9979996'."*

Inner Exception text: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Using a small test program I created I can successfully connect to the backend service using net.tcp, so I guess the problem must lie with my service being hosted by IIS. I have already enabled net.tcp protocol in IIS configuration. To be clear, the problem is not **hosting** a net.tcp service within IIS but rather to **access** from a service running in IIS.

I know I must be missing something here, hopefully one of you can point me in the right direction :)

Comment: What are the timings on your services? I know often by default its set to 10 mins time out

Comment: All timeouts are set to 10 minutes. However, the exception appears almost immediately so I don't think that is the reason.

Comment: Are the clients also IIS host services?   Your last line is access from a service running in IIS.

Comment: What account is your site running under?  You have to have at least SYSTEM_NETWORK or better to access network resources.

Comment: External client is an iPhone app. It connects to the service which in turn tries to call an internal service via net.tcp.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea: [Port sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772.aspx) isn't enabled on your internal server.

If this don't solve your problem you can configure [system.serviceModel diagnostics](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2005/12/15/5662.aspx) on both sides of your service to get further error details...